# htaccess redirect specific url to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect specific URL with params to another domain

http://domain.tld/buy/?w=X1234 to http://anotherdomain.tld/product.php?id=X1234

Here my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*buy/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/*buy/?w=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://anotherdomain.tld/product.php?id=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

but not working. maybe the problem is param ?w=

Thank you

UPDATE: i solve the problem by using Query string, after reading [How to REGEX and .htaccess rewrite url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318171/how-to-regex-and-htaccess-rewrite-url)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/*buy/$ http://anotherdomain.tld/product.php?id=%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Thank you stackoverflow and folks! i m start understanding regex from here ^_^

Answer (score 0):

That's right, your params won't be picked up, but they can be passed on.

Something like;

```
RewriteRule ^buy/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://anotherdomain.tld/product.php?id=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Where your original url would be; /buy/X1234

Comment: I m not allowed to change the w params. How to make `?w=` as string in htaccess regex