# How to hide the 1st variable in this url with .htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`blah.com/numberVariable/variable2.html`

I want to hide the number variable in the URL.

Here is my current code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  details.php query_string=$1&action=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  details.php?query_string=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\/[^\/\n]+
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dR6qO2/3)

Explaining:

```
\/           # match the first '/' character
[^\/\n]+     # and anything till the next '/' character or till the line's end
```

I'm assuming that `/numberVariable` is the first *folder*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could I get some help with the htaccess code? Whenever I made changes it goes into a redirect loop. Could someone explain what my lines of code means?

Comment: @neo. Well, I'm not a `htaccess` expert. But I found this answer: _http://stackoverflow.com/q/4318171/4227915_