# htaccess RewriteRule regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have hundreds of these old links I need to redirect.

Here is one example:

/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=433:seventh-character-code-categories-and-icd-10-cm&Itemid=101&showall=1

to

/seventh-character-code-categories-and-icd-10-cm

Essentially I need to remove the /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=433: part.

I tried this but I am getting confused with the [0-9] and : parts, so the following does not work:

RewriteRule ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=[0-9]:(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to REGEX and .htaccess rewrite url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318171/how-to-regex-and-htaccess-rewrite-url)

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to capture from after `:` to right before `&` in the query string you mentioned, then try this expression:

```
^[^\:]*\:([^\&]*)\&.*$
```

As @starkeen mentioned in comments, you got to check against the *query string*. This can be done using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

So if `index.php` is in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^\:]*\:([^\&]*)\&.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Here's another example. This one is for a sub folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/pages\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^\:]*\:([^\&]*)\&.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Also, notice the `?` at the end of the url `/pages/%1?`, this prevents from re-attaching the query string.

Another thing, captured groups will be set to variables `%{number}` since set in the RewriteCond.

BTW, depending on your server's configuration, you may need to add the NE flag,  like `[NE,L,R=301]` Plus test whether it is necessary to double escape the literal characters.

Comment: why you mach first ampersand? we neen everything before it and don't care  what is after including it

Comment: This will not work as you are matching against url query string in RewriteRule's pattern.

Comment: I made an update to the answer. I was not paying attention to your .htaccess structure before. Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

what is about direct approach. Skip all till semicolon, mach string till & and replace all with first much

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^:]+:([\w-]+[^&]).*
    RewriteRule .*$ \/%1?  [R=301,L]  

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Query string isn't part of match in RewriteRule directive. You have to capture query string using `% {QUERY_STRING}` variable separately using  a RewriteCond